# Get number of items in repeater during OnItemDataBound

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, collections, web-controls

I'm trying to get the number of items in a repeater whilst handling the `OnItemDataBound` event. What I'm trying to achieve it quite simple; I'm trying to **hide a certain label** on the **last item** within a repeater. Currently I'm hooking into the `ItemIndex` and `Items.Count`, however as it's during the `OnItemDataBound`, the index and count are incrementing together.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
Label myLabel = e.Item.FindControl<Label>("MyLabel");
if (myLabel != null)
{
    // as the item index is zero, I'll need to check against the collection minus 1?
    bool isLastItem = e.item.ItemIndex < (((Repeater)sender).Items.Count - 1);
    myLabel.Visible = !isLastItem;
}
```

I know that I could cast the `DataSource` to the collection of data items that were bound, however the `OnItemDataBound` event handler is being used across multiple repeater, so I'll need something slightly more generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you do something along the lines of, having set `Visible` to false by default:

```
if (e.Item.ItemIndex > 0)
{
     var previousItem = ((Repeater)sender).Items[e.Item.ItemIndex - 1];
     var previousLabel = previousItem.FindControl<Label>("MyLabel");
     if (previousLabel != null)
     {
         previousLabel.Visible = true;
     }
}
```

I'm not *sure* if this will work - I didn't know you could access `repeater.Items` until I saw your code - but it seems plausible.

Comment: This would work if I were trying to hide the item on the `first` item, but I want to hide it on the `last`. :)

Comment: @Richard Yup... set `Visible` to `false` by default, and then this code sets it to `true` on all but the last item. (On each binding, it finds the _previous_ label and shows it.)

Comment: ahh yeah, of course, d'uh. This is a possible solution, thank you.